# Flipper Lexical o Preprocessor Issue Flipper react-native ios build fails

Tags: ios, react-native, flipper

React native ios expo ejected app building fails due to `Flipper Lexical o Preprocessor Issue`, as shown in the image below,

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to add this line to Project -> Target -> Build Settings -> Search Paths -> Header Search Paths,
`"${PODS_ROOT}/libevent/include"`